# Registry key for virus protection

Tags: windows, windows-registry, anti-virus

Does anyone know if Action/Security Center uses a registry key (or file) to determine whether or not to notify the user that no virus protection is installed?  I'm not trying to turn off notifications, I'm simply trying to figure out an easy and accurate way to determine if any anti-virus is installed and hopefully the name of the AV as well.

This can't be something accessed through WMI or similar services as I only have access to the registry and files (using samba).

Comment: There are different mechanisms how to interface to the WSC, depending on the OS version, and all are under NDA. Not even sure I'm allowed to say that in particular, but ooops now I did :) ... none is via the registry.

Comment: "This can't be something accessed through WMI or similar services" - Too bad, else something like `WMIC /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName /Format:List` would have done the trick.

Comment: @Karan well that may end up helping thanks.  After I accepted the fact that I wouldn't be able to find it in the registry or a file I did a little research and found that samba has some WMI support (or maybe it's a fork of samba).  So if I ever get time I'll have to build this support into my product.